# bigotry, with or without prejudice

Tags: word-usage, nouns, american-english

Is prejudice required to be bigotry?

> big·ot·ry
>   *ˈbiɡətrē/*
>   *noun*
>
> intolerance toward those who hold different opinions from oneself

So, if you like having sex with little kids and in your 'opinion' you think it's ok, but I think you're a lunatic and a felon, I'm a bigot?

Comment: Originally *bigot* had a very positive sense - of a high placed, and high minded ecclesiastic. It came to have a pejorative connotation over time. Nowadays it always seems to imply a lack of proportion and reason in an attitude as much as prejudice.

Comment: @WS2 I was taught/told that having a post judgmental opinion based on a given set of facts was not bigotry. But then someone pulled this halfassed definition that does not include a word I always see in the definition 'prejudice' or pre judging (judging without any facts to based your judgement on). I have always been told that prejudice was an integral requirement to be 'bigotry'

Comment: I tend to think of *bigotry* as involving a *holier-than-thou* attitude - which does not suggest to me that prejudice is an essential component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think prejudice should be part and parcel of a *meaningful* definition of "bigotry", mere "intolerance" wouldn't do.

I'm intolerant of a lot of things, **torturing little girls just for the fun of it** being one.

I think merely equating bigotry with "intolerance toward other views" or some such leads to clear absurdities.

I'm not a bigot because I'm intolerant towards a view that says torturing little kids just for the fun of it is OK. Likewise, you're not a bigot for thinking pedophiles are morally reprehensible.

Answer (score 0):

Bigotry and prejudice (like racism and sexism) are words to describe power relations - the subjugation or discrimination of minorities by more powerful majorities, mostly.

They are not symmetrical relationships for the parties involved - so black people having strong and outrageous views about white people might be uncomfortable and unwarranted, but I don't think you can call it "racism".  Others might disagree.

But paedophiles are not an oppressed minority by most standards, and therefore you can dislike them as much as you wish, and subject them to appropriate penalties if you have the power to do so.

Comment: Just to clarify, if I state that "Donald Trump is a racist scumtard", this would 'not' be bigotry?

Comment: Probably not (Is truth a defence?), but to say all rich people or all men with rugs on their heads are x, might be prejudicial in a strict sense, but rarely bigotry.  And as noted above, the power relationship is fairly crucial in finding the right words to evaluate the speech or action being discussed.

Answer (score 0):

Your personal pronouns are off here. You can't start by bullying and browbeating your audience if your goal is to get honest answers from them.

If *someone* likes ... would be a better way to open a question. "You" in this case is a logical fallacy, akin to inquiries of the order of "When did you stop beating your wife?" or "When did you stop slowly poisoning your husband with arsenic?"

As for your question: bigotry or prejudice, it's all the same. Very few felons believe that society is not in one way or another prejudiced against them. Each individual must therefore decide for himself/herself whether bigotry is an objective or a subjective concept. If it is objective (i.e. universal), then the felons (most of them, anyway) are wrong. If the opposite is true, then they have a point.

Most relativists are convinced that all opinions, and all concepts, are subjective. In order to believe that some truths are universal, i.e. independent of people's opinions of them, one ultimately has to believe in God as well, logically speaking, since the difference between good and evil cannot be convincingly defined, nor grasped on any subliminal level, without the guidance of the Ten Commandments.

Answer (score 0):

The principal modern meaning of *bigot* per the OED is as follows, with recent examples:

> A person considered to adhere unreasonably or obstinately to a
>   particular religious belief, practice, etc.>
>
> 1938   P. Kavanagh Green Fool (1971) vi. 66   The Protestant
>   Rector..was a bit of a bigot.
>
> 2007   Calgary (Alberta) Sun (Nexis) 3 Feb. 15   This was intolerable
>   to Sunni bigots and Shiite fanatics alike.

For extended use the OED has the following:

> a fanatical adherent or believer; a person characterized by
>   obstinate, intolerant, or strongly partisan beliefs.

An earlier sense involving a notion of hypocrisy is now considered obsolete and has no OED examples since the mid-18th century.

There is no indication in any of the OED senses of ***prejudice*** being any component of *bigotry* - either essential or otherwise. The main idea seems to be that of ***intolerance***.